# Blackish Stains on bedframe slats

Tags: mold, bedroom, frame

I was in the process of disassembling my bed for an impending move, when I noticed some blackish stains on the bed slats.
Wondering what they are.

[image: boards with black marks]

Is it salvageable or should I throw it out completely?

Comment: Dump beach on them, air dry in sun, sand down, and repeat.  Should kill almost anything.  Replace mattress if any stain/smell in/on it.

Comment: Psst... @crip659... Answers go down there vvv !